# Pandas pd.read_csv isn't working for csv file greater than 900MB

Tags: python, csv, pandas, memory, ipython

My server is having 8GB of RAM and I am using pandas read_csv function for reading a csv file to a dataframe but it is executing as "Killed" for csv size greater than 900MB.

Please anyone help me handling this situation.
I am attaching my meminfo for getting advises on how to clear memory on the server
[Memory info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2McdF.png)

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` can return an iterator for large files.

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.read_csv('bar.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
```

This will return an iterator. You can then apply operations to the data in chunks using a for loop. It therefore does not read the whole file into memory at once. The chunk size is the number of rows per chunk.

It will be something like this:

```
for chunk in foo:
    # do something with chunk
```

**EDIT:** To the best of my knowledge you will have to apply functions like `unique` in chunks as well.

```
import numpy as np
unique_foo = []
for i in df:
    unique_foo.append(i['foo'].unique())

unique_foo = np.unique(unique_eff)
```

Comment: I am applying this method but how can I aggregate these chunks to apply operations like finding unique elements in the full data. Could you help out in this.

Comment: @Aakarsh see my edited answer. You have to do it like this as the actual `DataFrame` object is only exposed in the `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

*(You should be a little more specific about what code you're typing, and what kind of error you're receiving.)*

If `pandas` is not working with a file too large, you should revert to the more basic `csv` package. And you can still import in a DataFrame if you feel more comfortable that way.

Something like:

```
with open("file.csv", 'rb') as csv_file:
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(list(reader))
```

Comment: still I am not able to read into dataframe process is killing my csv file size is around 1001 MB.

Comment: Have you tried without using `pandas`?

    `df = list(reader)`

Comment: its not working either way, getting "Killed" as output.

Comment: I am adding my memory info please tell me how to clear unnecessary memory usage.